# Free variable create GetWindowDC in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have a component of skin, which paints a ComboBox, like this:

```
procedure TBaseComboBox.DrawBorders;
var
  DC: HDC;
begin
  DC := GetWindowDC(Handle);
  try
    DrawControlBorder(DC);

    if Style <> csSimple then
      DrawButtonBorder(DC);

  finally
    ReleaseDC(DC, Handle);
  end;
end;
```

My problem is that when running the ReleaseDC, the component is not destroyed. I managed to reach this conclusion, using the program GDIView 1.6

What should I do to try to destroy this variable.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Legacy code, we are looking at the problem of Out of system resources. We're changing carefully to reduce the impacts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameters in your `ReleaseDC()` call are backwards.  Read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162920.aspx).  The first parameter needs to be the `HWND` that the `HDC` came from, and the second parameter needs to be the `HDC` itself:

```
//ReleaseDC(DC, Handle);
ReleaseDC(Handle, DC);
```

Comment: D'oh! Of course! I feel silly for missing that. Another good advert for checking return values.